# How do you DI a filter for another filter in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, filter

I'm attempting to unit test a filter. This filter has a dependency on another filter. I have been unable to mock this filter. I've seen ways of mocking filters for *controllers* and I've seen ways of testing filters in isolation, but not this. I've tried simply providing the mock filter to no avail:

```
// compacted for brevity
var someService = {};
var injectedFilter = function(input) { return output; }
beforeEach(function() {
    // inject mocked dependencies
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('someService', someService);
        $provide.value('injectedFilter', injectedFilter); // with Filter suffix
        ...
```

I've tried clobbering the filter via the `$filterProvider.register` but it seems to have no effect. I even tried using Jasmine's `spyOn` with `.and.callFake` to just mock it all out but because the syntax is `filter("name")` and it doesn't operate on an object, it fails.

What is the correct way of DIing a filter for another filter?

Comment: Why you need to mock a filter, why not using the original?

Comment: Because I want to test this filter in isolation from the other, which I separately test. I would prefer to not be testing multiple pieces of logic in my unit tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try using `$provide.factory`:

```
$provide.factory('injectedFilter', injectedFilter);
```

---

#### It's the same as using `$filterProvider.register` like so:

```
$filterProvider.register('injected', injectedFilter);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that 'injectedFilter' in this case needs to be a wrapped function e.g. injectedFilter = function() { return function(input) { return output; }; };